# window.scrollBy() Not Working

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to scroll page on the load of angularJS controller, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
window.scrollBy(0, scroll);
```

Where scroll is correct amount of pixel obtained from local storage.
I think it can be because my url contains hash like this, and i cannot change it:

```
http://localhost:8080/_user/index.html#/
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Function is called in:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll = localStorage.getItem("scrollOffset");
    window.scrollBy(0, scroll);
});
```

Comment: How about an example, or some code?  Is scroll actually set by the time `scrollBy` is called?  Is `scrollBy` actually called? How is `scrollBy` called, a click, just pasted in the top of your controller, an IIFE?

Comment: Yes, it is called and yes, it is correctly set.